# Jquery: select only one class onclick - not all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby

I am trying to set a specific css class to some images when clicked.

Here is my code:

```
<%= image_tag ('snapchat.png'), class: "img-rounded", id: "icon-hover", width: "50px" %>
<%= image_tag ('tinder.png'), class: "img-rounded", id: "icon-hover", width: "50px" %>
<%= image_tag ('tumblr.png'), class: "img-rounded", id: "icon-hover", width: "50px" %>
```

And my jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.img-rounded', function (){
      $('.img-rounded').css({
        '-webkit-filter':'grayscale(0%)',
        'filter':'grayscale(0%)',
      });
    });
```

The function works great, the problem is that when I click on one image, it gives the css attribtues to all others images. How could I only targert one element at a time ?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: My images are wrapped inside parent elemnts like this:

```
<b href="" class="wechat" id="icon-hover" style="text-decoration:none">
  <%= image_tag ('wechat.png'), class: "img-rounded", id: "icon-hover", width: "50px" %>
</b>
```

So even when using the "this" handler it doesn't respond:

```
$(document).on('click', '.img-rounded', function (){
      $(this).css({
        '-webkit-filter':'grayscale(0%)',
        'filter':'grayscale(0%)',
      });
    });
```

Comment: Use `$(this)` inside handler. `$('.img-rounded').css({` ==> `$(this).css({`. I'd recommend you to use a CSS class and add the class by using `.addClass('className)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.img-rounded', function (){
      $(this).css({
        '-webkit-filter':'grayscale(0%)',
        'filter':'grayscale(0%)',
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you !! it is working well when images are not wrapped inside parents elements. I edited my question, do you have any ideas ? I tried to update the jquery but it does not work.

Comment: $('img.img-rounded).on('click',function (){
      $(this).css({
        '-webkit-filter':'grayscale(0%)',
        'filter':'grayscale(0%)',
      });
    }); you can try with a restrictive selector

Comment: can you provide a fiddle with you issue?

Comment: Wow, that's the id of the parent element that was the probleme, confusing the jquery. all good. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).css({
    '-webkit-filter':'grayscale(0%)',
    'filter':'grayscale(0%)',
});
```

which means that you are assigning the current object to a variable named $this. It is not a keyword.